# Conditional Formatting based on first Column non-zero values

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this on a pivot table? I've been scratching my head about it but can't work it out

[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, following this guide, so that we can see your data.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: Yes, this can be done. However, I concur with @kirkg13: the only efficient way to share a solution is if you'll share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a realistic representative sample from it such as what is shown in the post), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."